# Replace specific strings with specific images in Google Sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

Essentially I am trying to build a google sheet that will convert specific strings into specific images for a Magic the Gathering google sheet.

For example, if I have the text **{3}{G}** I'd like to replace the {3} with [image: 3mana] and the {G} with [image: Gmana].

I tried to use the substitute function, referencing cells where I had the images stored, but it didn't work. Any help anyone could provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know [tag:js]? Seems like it's only possible with a complicated script.

Comment: As [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) mention. It might be unmanageable since you will have to Split the text, for example: `=SPLIT(A1, "}{")` and also a bunch of if with the URL of the images with the formula `=IMAGE("URL-with-the-image")`.

And depending on how many images you need to fill out, there will be too many `IF` on it.

Comment: **Note:**
*Additionally, with formulas. You will not be able to add 2 images in the same cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with some compromises, you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""&REGEXEXTRACT(""&A2:A, 
 REPT("(.)", LEN(A2:A))), {F1:F&"", G1:G}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]